# Postgres running parallel queries (cross joins on large tables)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, parallel-processing

I need to run queries of the following type:

```
SELECT * FROM A CROSS JOIN B WHERE myfunction(A.x,B.y) = Z
```

Because the query is slow I would like to use all processors available to speed it up. 
I have only very basic knowledge of relational databases so even "obvious" comments are welcome.

- Postgres v 9.4.4  (upgrade is not an option due to some constraints)
- A has 3 mil rows
- B can have 100k rows (but could have like 10M rows in future)
- A,B have indexed columns
- myfunction (A.x,B.y) takes advantage of indexes on A.x, B.y  - without them it is even much more slower.

What would be a reasonable solution?
At present 10k x 2M query using 50 processors with naive split suggested below took about 20 min.

I am considering running cross joins on parts of B in parallel. B would be split by values of ID (integer primary key)

```
SELECT * FROM A CROSS JOIN B WHERE myfunction(A.x,B.y) = Z  AND  A.id BETWEEN N and M.
```

and the run multiple "psql -d mydatabase  subqueryNumberX.sql" commands using gnu parallel.

Some questions:

1. If I have an indexed table T and use a SELECT from it within another query would index of T used in search? or this subSELECT destroys it?
2. In my query above, would selection of a part of the table  (WHERE A.id BETWEEN N and M) prevent using index?
3. When a (slow) cross-join on a table is in progress is such table accessible for other operations (next cross-join)?

Comment: How does `myfunction()` make use of indexes?  What is it doing behind the scenes.  If you have 3 million rows and 100 thousand rows in a cross join, the cross join processes 300 billion rows (3E11 rows).  At 1000 ms (aka 1 second) per row, and at 3E7 seconds per year, and let's assume for giggles that you have 1000 CPUs available, you should get an answer in about 10 years. When you get 100 times as much data, you might get an answer about the start of the next millennium — unless the system has to be upgraded in the interim, or security patches fixed. You've got problems!

Comment: The function `myfunction` must be called 100k * 10M = 1,000,000,000,000 times to perform a join. Assumming that 1 call takes only 1 milisecond, you need 1,000,000,000 seconds (11,574 days) to process this join on 1 CPU. If you buy 11574 processors, then the query takes 1 day (24 hours) - still assumming that 1 call of the function takes only 1 milisecond. But if it take 200 milisecond instead of 1 ms .... you can do these calculations yourself.

Comment: there must be an error in the estimation of time the functions needs for calculations. it seems that postgres  remembers some results from previous rounds of calculation.  10k x 2M query using 50 processors with naive split suggested in my question above took about 20 min. It would be possible to improve it probably if I knew more about sql (see my questions above).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is (still) rather vague.

1. For a cross join, indexes are not necessarily of much use, but it depends on the columns which are indexed and the columns referenced in the query and the size of the rows in the table.  If the index is on the relevant columns, then maybe the optimizer will do an 'index only' scan instead of a 'full table scan' and benefit from the smaller amount of I/O.  However, since you have `SELECT *`, you are selecting all columns from `A` and `B` so the full rows will need to be read (but see point 2). There isn't a sub-select in the query, so it is mystifying to ask about the sub-select destroying anything.
2. Nominally, you might get some benefit from moving the WHERE clause into a sub-select such as:

   ```
   SELECT *
     FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id BETWEEN N AND M) AS A1
    CROSS JOIN B
    WHERE myFunction(A1.x, B.y) = Z
   ```

   However, it would be a feeble optimizer that would not do that automatically.  The range condition might make an index on `A.id` attractive, especially if M and N represent a small fraction of the total range of values in `A.id`.  So, the optimizer should use an index with `A.id` as the leading or sole component to allow it to speed up the query.  The condition won't prevent the use of any index — indexes almost certainly won't be used otherwise.
3. A slow query does not inhibit other queries; it may inhibit updates while it is running, or it may stress the MVCC (multi-version concurrency control) mechanisms of the DBMS.